# express-session: cookie no aparece en el navegador

Tags: nodejs, angular, express-session

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web utilizando Nodejs y Angular, para los cuales tengo experiencia nula (hasta ahora siempre había utilizado PHP y JQuery). He ido superando los diversos problemas que me he encontrado con ayuda de internet, excepto el que me dispongo a explicar: no soy capaz de hacer funcionar las sesiones en Nodejs. 
Lo que ocurre es que cada vez que realizo una petición al servidor, la variable que guarda la sesión cambia (id, datos...). Además, la cookie no aparece por ningún lado en el navegador.

Index.js:

```js
class Server {

    public app: Application;
    public sesion: any;
    public uuid: any;

    constructor() {        
        this.app = express();
        this.sesion = session();        
        this.config();  
        this.routes();              
    }

    config(): void {
        this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
        this.app.use(morgan('dev'));
        this.app.use((cors())); 
        this.app.use(session({
            secret: 'provisional',
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: { secure: false }
        }))              
    }
    

    routes(): void {
        this.app.use('/', indexRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/productos', productsRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/categorias', categoriasRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/subcategorias', subcategoriasRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/gastos', gastosRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/detalles-gasto', detallesGastosRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/proveedores', proveedoresRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/personas', personasRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/pagos', pagosRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/socios', sociosRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/ventas', ventasRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/detalles-venta', detallesVentasRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/cobros', cobrosRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/caja', cajaRoutes);
        this.app.use('/api/login', loginRoutes);        
    }
    

    start(): void {
        this.app.listen(this.app.get('port'), () => {
            console.log("Server running on port " + this.app.get('port'));
        });
    }
}


try {
    const server = new Server();
    server.start(); 
    const db = new DB();
    db.createTables();
    db.closeDB();   
 
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

LoginController:

```js
export class LoginController {

    public async getCredentials (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>{

        const db = await new DB();
        
        try {           
            await db.getOneByID(`
                SELECT user, password, salt
                FROM usuarios
                WHERE user = ?`, [req.body.user]
                );

            const result = db.getRows();
            if(db.getNoResults()){
                res.json(db.getNoResultsMsg());
            }
            else {                
                const inputUser = result.user;
                const inputPassword = req.body.password;
                const passwordHash = result.password;
                const salt = result.salt;
                const passwordCheck = this.validatePasswordHash(inputPassword, salt);
                if (passwordCheck === passwordHash) {
                    res.json({message: 'Login OK!'});
                    if (req.session) {
                        req.session.user = inputUser;
                        console.log(req.sessionID);
                    }                   
                }
                else {
                    res.json({message: 'Password incorrecto'});
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.json('Error: ' + error);      
        }     
        finally {
            db.closeDB();
        }  
    }
    [---]
```

El sessionID cambia cuando el usuario accede a otra ruta (es generado nuevamente), y el valor guardado en req.session.user se pierde.

Seguramente estaré cometiendo algún fallo de bulto debido a mi falta de experiencia con Nodejs. Estaría muy agradecido si alguien me pudiera echar un cable porque estoy totalmente estancado.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he solucionado el problema por el cual la cookie no llegaba al navegador: está relacionado con el "Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado (CORS)". Además de instalar y configurar cors en el servidor, es necesario añadir en cada petición realizada desde el cliente (angular) la opción "withCredentials: true" ([www.tsmean.com/articles/authentication/express-session-angular](https://www.tsmean.com/articles/authentication/express-session-angular/)).

```js
getGastos(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/gastos`, 
      {withCredentials:true}
    );
}
```